# Can APFS Encrypted leverage SSD hardware-based encryption?

Tags: ssd, encryption, macos

I recently bought an NVME to use with an external case that I have. I formatted it with APFS encrypted (will only use it with my Macbook and iPad), because I want to have an extra layer of security when carrying it around.

The issue is that the APFS encrypted had a big hit on performance. From the usual 900MB/s it dropped to 250MB/s.

Checking the specs of the SSD I found it doesn’t have 256-bit AES hardware-based encryption support.

Wondering if buying one with hardware-based encryption will help with performance when using APFS encrypted. Or this hardware-based encryption only works with manufacturer's proprietary software?